# Multi-touch is not working in the iphone app I'm building

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod-touch

I have the following code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


NSUInteger touchCount = 0;
// Enumerates through all touch objects
for (UITouch *touchb in touches){
    touchCount++;
}


// When multiple touches, report the number of touches. 
if (touchCount > 1) {
    lblStatustouch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tracking %d touches", touchCount];
} else {
    lblStatustouch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tracking 1 touch", touchCount];
}
```

When I run it, it never detects more than one touch.  Is there some setting that may prevent my app from taking multiple touches?  Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable "Multiple Touch" on your View in InterfaceBuilder

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090227-rpkafsxtg56pujk1h1583if88i.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090227-rpkafsxtg56pujk1h1583if88i.jpg)

or if you have created the View in code it's set with

```
[theView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Thank You, I created the view in code and was going nuts trying to figure it out.  I did that and now it's working great!

Comment: Bryan, if this is the right answer, you should "accept" it by clicking the little green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also know that you will only get multiple touches in touchesMoved if both fingers are moving *at the same time*. If you have a single finger fixed on the screen, and move a second finger around, the phone will only report the finger that is moving.